# xcb keyboard button masks meaning

Tags: x11, xcb

I'm trying to figure what keys are handled by:

- XCB_MOD_MASK_1
- XCB_MOD_MASK_2
- XCB_MOD_MASK_3
- XCB_MOD_MASK_4
- XCB_MOD_MASK_5

in xcb, for XCB_MOD_MASK_1 it seems to be Alt (i'm correct?), but for others button i cannot find the mapping anywhere (i tried to google them before posting, but with no success).

So what are the usual key associated to these masks?

Comment: Could you create a small program to capture any event and then try to press any possible modifier (even combinations of them) to see if you get a match?

Comment: Usually Mask1 is Alt or Meta, Mask2 is Num lock, Mask3 is AltGr, Mask4 is Win, and Mask5 is Scroll lock, but this varies between X implementations and/or keyboard models.

Comment: Thank you n.m, if you post your comment as an answer i'll be happy to accept it :)

Comment: Agree with Ivan. @n.m. if you can move to solution i would love to upvote!

Comment: Sorry, I got distracted a bit :)

Comment: Wow a bit??? :D Only 3 years later!!! :) :) Anyway i will accept your answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually Mask1 is Alt or Meta, Mask2 is Num lock, Mask3 is AltGr, Mask4 is Win, and Mask5 is Scroll lock, but this varies between X implementations and/or keyboard models.

Source: my own computer running X11, and various bits and pieces of code lying around on the 'net. Not all of them are consistent, e.g. some say Mod1 is Alt and Mod4 is Meta.

X11 programs normally let users configure actions corresponding to Mask1 ... Mask5, and have them sort out which key sets which mask.

Answer (score 7):

You can actually configure what those keys (or any keys) are mapped to, with a utility like `xmodmap`. In the [X Window System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) there are **eight modifiers**. The 8 modifiers are

0. `shift`
1. `lock`
2. `control`
3. `mod1`
4. `mod2`
5. `mod3`
6. `mod4`
7. `mod5`

To see what keys are currently mapped to these modifiers you can run `xmodmap -pm`, which prints the **modifier map**. Eg. for me the output is

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

So `Alt` generates `mod1`, for instance.

Now to change `mod1` through `mod5` with `xmodmap`, open `~/.Xmodmap` and write something like:

```
clear mod1
clear mod2
clear mod3
clear mod4
clear mod5

add mod1 = Alt_L Alt_R Meta_L
add mod2 = Num_Lock
add mod3 = ISO_Level3_Shift
add mod4 = Super_L Super_R Super_L Hyper_L
add mod5 = ISO_Level5_Shift
```

Then run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`.

And now, for instance, `ISO_Level3_Shift` is what gives you `mod3`.

How you can actually get a key from your keyboard to generate the keycode that corresponds to `ISO_Level3_Shift` is another challenge.

Eg. to get keycode `100` to generate `ISO_Level3_Shift` (which is now `mod3`), add the following to your `~/.Xmodmap` file and run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`.

```
keycode 100 = ISO_Level3_Shift
```

The keycode with, for instance, value `100` should be generated by `udev`. When you press a physical key in your keyboard, the microcontroller/firmware maps that physical key to a **scancode** and sends that scancode through the USB interface. Then `udev` maps that scancode to a Linux `kernel keycode`. Then X11 maps that kernel keycode to an `X11 keycode`. And then X11 maps that X11 keycode to an `X11 keysym`. Needless to say, this mapping is unnecessarily complicated. (In particular, I almost always ignore `X11 keysyms` and work with raw `X11 keycodes`.)

You might hear that `xmodmap` is deprecated, and that you should mess with XKB config files and stuff, but using XKB is much, much, much worse.

(Keyboards are really simple (just a circuit+microcontroller that scans the physical key matrix, keyboard-side firmware that knows USB HID, and then a kernel-side driver that maps firmware-dependent scancodes to standardized keycodes), but people have made them really complicated. Also, scancodes/keycodes should've been 32-bit from the start.)

---

In the X protocol, the 8 modifiers (`shift`, ..., `mod1`, ..., `mod5`) have a bitmask associated to them. This is the bitmask that XCB implements using a C **enum**, and its precise values are:

```
enum xcb_mod_mask_t{
  XCB_MOD_MASK_SHIFT                    = 1<<0,
  XCB_MOD_MASK_LOCK                     = 1<<1,
  XCB_MOD_MASK_CONTROL                  = 1<<2,
  XCB_MOD_MASK_1                        = 1<<3,
  XCB_MOD_MASK_2                        = 1<<4,
  XCB_MOD_MASK_3                        = 1<<5,
  XCB_MOD_MASK_4                        = 1<<6,
  XCB_MOD_MASK_5                        = 1<<7,
  XCB_MOD_MASK_ANY                      = 1<<15,
};
```

These values aren't XCB's choice, but they're prescribed by the X protocol specification and you can use them when talking to the X server through the X protocol. Eg. when the X server sends you an `XCB_KEY_PRESS` event, this event is a 32-byte struct, and one of its fields is a bitmask where the bits are set according to the modifiers that were pressed during that key press event. Eg. if bit 0 is set, it means `XCB_MOD_MASK_SHIFT` is set, meaning the `Shift` modifier was help down.